# How to redirect to the page that I want after logged in and display username after successful login

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on my project. I have problem with login system. First, I want to redirect to the page that I want. Second, I want to display username(Same as username for logging in) on navbar.

I already tried "header()" for redirecting but it doesn't work. It display "Object Not Found" page. I tried "window.location.assign()" too but it display same result as "header()".

index.php

```php
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        .
        .
        .
    <title>Online Stock Trading</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
          .
          .
          .
      <form class="form-inline" action="php/login_page.php" method="post">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <button class="btn btn-success my-2 mr-sm-2" id="login-btn" type="submit">LOGIN</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-2 mr-sm-2" id="sign_up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">SIGN UP</button>
      </form>
    </nav>
          .
          .
          .
</body>
</html>
```

login_page.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Username, Password FROM trader_data WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password'")
    or die("Failed to query database".mysql_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['Username']==$username && $row['Password']==$password)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    echo "<script>
            alert('Login Success!!');
            window.location.assign('logged_in.php');
    </script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script>
            alert('Failed to login!!');
            window.location.assign('index.php');
    </script>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

logged_in.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        .
        .
        .
    <title>Online Stock Trading</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
          .
          .
          .
          <div class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <?php echo $_SESSION["username"];?>
            </a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Account</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">History</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Portfolio</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>
        .
        .
        .
</body>
</html>
```

I expect my web will go to "logged_in.php" page after logged in. Then, display username that used to log in on "index.php" page.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Look slike you are using Plain Text Passwords, thats very bad practice. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.

Comment: It is far easier and cleaner and more efficient to redirect to another page in PHP using a `header('Location: logged_in.php');` (for example)

Comment: Did you try `header('Location: php/logged_in.php');`

Comment: I already try header('Location: logged_in.php'); and also header('Location: php/logged_in.php'); but it display the same.

Comment: I place "login_page" in php folder but the rest is outside. Does it involves?

Comment: Did you try `header('../logged_in.php');`

Comment: header('../logged_in.php'); is work. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `window.location.href` for redirecting. And to pass in a value to another page, you can use sessions or make a `GET` request.

**Using Sessions:**

login_page.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
?>
<script>
window.location.href="logged_in.php";
</script>
```

logged_in.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

**Using A `GET` Request**

login_page.php

```html
<script>
window.location.href="logged_in.php?username=<?php echo $username;?>"
</script>
```

logged_in.php

```html
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
?>
```